# org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(Ljava/net/URI;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/test/DeploymentContext;

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

I'm preparing an application which have some test cases and this application is working on JERSY api to be provide REST services. Without test cases it will be a successful build, but when I use to write the test cases with JUNIT then I get the error

The following log error to console:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(Ljava/net/URI;Lorg/glassfish/jersey/test/DeploymentContext;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/test/spi/TestContainer;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)
    at com.verizon.uis.rest.mock.RestServiceTestBase.setUp(RestServiceTestBase.java:90)
    at com.verizon.uis.rest.resources.AuthIdentityTest.setUp(AuthIdentityTest.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

`RestTestBaseClass` which extends `JerssyTest` class. So when we check this api in to the JUNIT cases then we are getting the error stated. Here's the `RestTestBaseClass` class.

```
public abstract class RestServiceTestBase extends JerseyTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(RestServiceTestBase.class.getName());

    protected static MemoryHandler logHandler = new MemoryHandler();

    public RestServiceTestBase() throws TestContainerException {
        super();
    }

    public RestServiceTestBase(final TestContainerFactory testContainerFactory) {
        super(testContainerFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new RestApplicationBase();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupOnce() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT,
                String.valueOf(getPort(0)));

        System.setProperty(TestProperties.RECORD_LOG_LEVEL,
                String.valueOf(Level.ALL.intValue()));

        final LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
        final Enumeration<String> loggers = lm.getLoggerNames();
        while (loggers.hasMoreElements()) {
            final String name = loggers.nextElement();
            final Logger logger = lm.getLogger(name);
            if (logger != null && logHandler != null) {
                logger.addHandler(logHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        final ConfigurationManager cm = SingletonFactory
                .getInstance(ConfigurationManager.class);

        final InMemoryConfiguration apigee = new InMemoryConfiguration(
                Configuration.CTX_APIGEE);
        cm.registerConfiguration(apigee);
        apigee.setSetting("API_MIN_VERSION", "1");
        apigee.setSetting("API_MAX_VERSION", "6");
    }

    protected <R> R post(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final String mediaType,
            final Class<R> responseClass, final Object entity)
            throws JAXBException {
        final Response response = WebServiceUtil.post(resource, headers,
                mediaType, entity);
        assertNotNull(response);

        assertEquals("Unexpected Media Type", mediaType, response
                .getMediaType().toString());

        final R postResponse = response.readEntity(responseClass);
        assertNotNull(postResponse);
        print(responseClass, postResponse, mediaType);
        return postResponse;
    }

    protected <R> R post(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final Class<R> responseClass,
            final Object entity) throws JAXBException {
        return post(resource, headers, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
                responseClass, entity);
    }

    protected <R> R post(final WebTarget resource,
            final Class<R> responseClass, final Object entity)
            throws JAXBException {
        return post(resource, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, responseClass,
                entity);
    }

    protected <R> R put(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final String mediaType,
            final Class<R> responseClass, final Object entity)
            throws JAXBException {
        final Response response = WebServiceUtil.put(resource, headers,
                mediaType, entity);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals("Unexpected Media Type", mediaType, response
                .getMediaType().toString());

        final R putResponse = response.readEntity(responseClass);
        assertNotNull(putResponse);
        print(responseClass, putResponse, mediaType);
        return putResponse;
    }

    protected <R> R put(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final Class<R> responseClass,
            final Object entity) throws JAXBException {
        return put(resource, headers, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, responseClass,
                entity);
    }

    protected <R> R put(final WebTarget resource, final Class<R> responseClass,
            final Object entity) throws JAXBException {
        return put(resource, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, responseClass,
                entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <R> R get(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final String mediaType,
            final Class<R> responseClass) throws JAXBException {
        final Response response = WebServiceUtil.get(resource, headers,
                mediaType);
        assertNotNull("Response is null!", response);
        assertNotNull("Response media type is null!", response.getMediaType());
        assertEquals("Unexpected Media Type", mediaType, response
                .getMediaType().toString());

        if (Response.class.equals(responseClass)) {
            return (R) response;
        }
        final R getResponse = response.readEntity(responseClass);
        if (mediaType != null && "application/pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(mediaType)) {
            return getResponse;
        }

        assertNotNull(getResponse);
        print(responseClass, getResponse, mediaType);
        return getResponse;
    }

    protected <R> R get(final WebTarget resource, final Class<R> responseClass)
            throws JAXBException {
        return get(resource, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, responseClass);
    }

    protected <R> R delete(final WebTarget resource,
            final Map<String, Object> headers, final String mediaType,
            final Class<R> responseClass, final Object entity)
            throws JAXBException {
        final Response response = WebServiceUtil.delete(resource, headers,
                mediaType, entity);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals("Unexpected Media Type", mediaType, response
                .getMediaType().toString());

        final R deleteResponse = response.readEntity(responseClass);
        assertNotNull(deleteResponse);
        print(responseClass, deleteResponse, mediaType);
        return deleteResponse;
    }

    protected <R> R delete(final WebTarget resource,
            final Class<R> responseClass, final Object entity)
            throws JAXBException {
        return delete(resource, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, responseClass,
                entity);
    }

    protected <J> void print(final Class<J> jaxbClass, final J jaxbObject,
            final String mediaType) throws JAXBException {
        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equalsIgnoreCase(mediaType)) {
            printJson(jaxbClass, jaxbObject);
        } else {
            printXml(jaxbClass, jaxbObject);
        }
    }

    protected <J> void printXml(final Class<J> jaxbClass, final J jaxbObject)
            throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbClass);
        final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbObject, System.out);
    }

    protected <J> void printJson(final Class<J> jaxbClass, final J jaxbObject)
            throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbClass);
        final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        final org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration config = new org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration();
        final MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(
                config);
        final Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        final XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = new MappedXMLStreamWriter(con,
                writer);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbObject, xmlStreamWriter);
    }

    protected static int getPort(final int defaultPort) {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        int port = -1;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(defaultPort);
            port = server.getLocalPort();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // ignore
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, e.getMessage(), e);
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
        if (port != -1 || defaultPort == 0) {
            return port;
        }
        return getPort(0);
    }

    protected void writeLogsToStdOut() {
        final List<LogRecord> logs = logHandler.getLogs();
        for (final LogRecord r : logs) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, r.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected void assertResponseSuccess(
            final IUISResponseStatus uisStatusResponse) {
        assertResponseStatus(uisStatusResponse, 0, "SUCCESS");
    }

    protected void assertResponseFailure(
            final IUISResponseStatus uisStatusResponse) {
        assertResponseStatus(uisStatusResponse, 1, "FAILED");
    }

    protected void assertResponseStatus(
            final IUISResponseStatus uisStatusResponse, final int code,
            final String label) {
        assertNotNull("UIS Response Status not provided", uisStatusResponse);
        assertEquals("Request did not succeed -- bad status code", code,
                uisStatusResponse.getStatusCd());
        assertEquals("Request did not succeed -- bad status label", label,
                uisStatusResponse.getStatusLabel());
    }

    protected void assertMessagesContain(final String messageType,
            final List<IUISResponseStatusMessage> messages,
            final String... codes) {
        final Set<String> codeset = new HashSet<String>();
        for (final IUISResponseStatusMessage m : messages) {
            codeset.add(m.getMessageCode());
        }
        if (codes == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (final String code : codes) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                continue;
            }
            assertTrue("Missing " + messageType + " " + code,
                    codeset.contains(code));
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea about how this error can be resolved?

Comment: Improved formatting and corrected spelling